# How to add function for mqtt server authentication

Tags: c, mqtt

How can I add the functions for username and password to authen mqtt broker.

The original file has not section for authentication. How can I adding function for username and password in authentication mqtt server?

This file has mqtt.h that is sitting parameters (such as hotsname, port, etc.). and I have added parameter for username and password in mqtt.h following this

```
struct mqtt_handle_s {
  // Public members
  char *host;
  int port;
  char *username;
  char *password;
  char *client_id;
  mqtt_on_connect_t on_connect;
  mqtt_on_message_t on_message;
  // Private members
  struct mosquitto *client;
  char *topic_list;
  size_t topic_size;
};
```

and then how can I adding the function for running that parameter to using in mqtt server authentication?

the main code is following..

#mqtt.c full code.

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "app_log.h"
#include "mqtt.h"

// Check if libmosquitto version is at least 1.5.7
#if LIBMOSQUITTO_VERSION_NUMBER < 1005007
#warning Untested libmosquitto version!
#endif

#define QOS                    1
#define KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL_SEC 30
#define LOOP_TIMEOUT_MS        1
#define LOG_MASK               MOSQ_LOG_NONE

static void mqtt_on_connect(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, int rc);
static void mqtt_on_disconnect(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, int rc);
static void mqtt_on_message(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *message);
static void mqtt_on_log(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, int level, const char *str);
static const char * mqtt_err2str(int rc);

mqtt_status_t mqtt_init(mqtt_handle_t *handle)
{
  mqtt_status_t ret = MQTT_SUCCESS;
  int rc = MOSQ_ERR_ERRNO;           // return code if mosquitto_new() fails
  struct mosquitto *mosq;

  mosquitto_lib_init();

  mosq = mosquitto_new(handle->client_id, true, handle);
  if (mosq != NULL) {
    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosq, mqtt_on_connect);
    mosquitto_disconnect_callback_set(mosq, mqtt_on_disconnect);
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosq, mqtt_on_message);
    mosquitto_log_callback_set(mosq, mqtt_on_log);

    rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, handle->host, handle->port, KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL_SEC);
  }

  if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
    app_log("MQTT init failed: '%s'\n", mqtt_err2str(rc));
    ret = MQTT_ERROR_CONNECT;
    handle->client = NULL;
    if (mosq != NULL) {
      mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
    }
  } else {
    handle->client = mosq;
  }

  handle->topic_list = NULL;
  handle->topic_size = 0;

  return ret;
}

mqtt_status_t mqtt_publish(mqtt_handle_t *handle, const char *topic, const char *payload)
{
  mqtt_status_t ret = MQTT_SUCCESS;
  int rc;
  int mid;

  if (handle->client != NULL) {
    rc = mosquitto_publish(handle->client, &mid, topic, strlen(payload), payload, QOS, false);
    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
      app_log("MQTT publish attempt failed: '%s'\n", mqtt_err2str(rc));
      ret = MQTT_ERROR_PUBLISH;
    }
  } else {
    ret = MQTT_ERROR_PUBLISH;
  }

  return ret;
}

mqtt_status_t mqtt_step(mqtt_handle_t *handle)
{
  mqtt_status_t ret = MQTT_SUCCESS;
  int rc;

  if (handle->client != NULL) {
    rc = mosquitto_loop(handle->client, LOOP_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);
    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
      app_log("MQTT loop failed: '%s'\n", mqtt_err2str(rc));
      ret = MQTT_ERROR_STEP;
    }
  } else {
    ret = MQTT_ERROR_STEP;
  }

  return ret;
}

mqtt_status_t mqtt_subscribe(mqtt_handle_t *handle, const char *topic)
{
  mqtt_status_t ret = MQTT_SUCCESS;
  int rc;
  size_t topic_size;

  if (handle->client != NULL) {
    // Try to subscribe to topic.
    rc = mosquitto_subscribe(handle->client, NULL, topic, QOS);

    if ((rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) && (rc != MOSQ_ERR_NO_CONN)) {
      app_log("MQTT subscribe attempt failed to topic '%s': '%s'\n", topic, mqtt_err2str(rc));
      ret = MQTT_ERROR_SUBSCRIBE;
    }

    // Append topic to topic list.
    topic_size = strlen(topic) + 1;
    handle->topic_list = realloc(handle->topic_list, handle->topic_size + topic_size);
    if (handle->topic_list == NULL) {
      app_log("MQTT failed to append topic to topic list.\n");
      ret = MQTT_ERROR_SUBSCRIBE;
    } else {
      strcpy(&handle->topic_list[handle->topic_size], topic);
      handle->topic_size += topic_size;
    }
  } else {
    ret = MQTT_ERROR_SUBSCRIBE;
  }

  return ret;
}

mqtt_status_t mqtt_deinit(mqtt_handle_t *handle)
{
  int rc;

  if (handle->client != NULL) {
    rc = mosquitto_disconnect(handle->client);

    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
      app_log("MQTT failed to disconnect: '%s', continue deinit.\n", mqtt_err2str(rc));
    }

    mosquitto_destroy(handle->client);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
    if (handle->topic_list != NULL) {
      free(handle->topic_list);
    }
  }

  return MQTT_SUCCESS;
}

static void mqtt_on_connect(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, int rc)
{
  mqtt_handle_t *handle = (mqtt_handle_t *)obj;
  size_t topic_start = 0;
  char *topic;
  int ret = MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS;

  app_log("MQTT connect status '%s'\n", mosquitto_connack_string(rc));

  if (rc == 0) {
    if (handle->on_connect != NULL) {
      handle->on_connect(handle);
    }
    while (topic_start < handle->topic_size) {
      topic = &handle->topic_list[topic_start];
      ret = mosquitto_subscribe(mosq, NULL, topic, QOS);
      topic_start += strlen(topic) + 1;
      if (ret != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
        app_log("MQTT subscribe attempt failed to topic '%s': '%s'\n", topic, mqtt_err2str(ret));
      }
    }
  }
}

static void mqtt_on_disconnect(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, int rc)
{
  int ret;

  app_log("MQTT disconnected with reason '%d'\n", rc);

  if (rc != 0) {
    ret = mosquitto_reconnect(mosq);
    app_log("MQTT reconnection attempt with status '%s'\n", mqtt_err2str(ret));
  }
}

static void mqtt_on_message(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *message)
{
  mqtt_handle_t *handle = (mqtt_handle_t *)obj;
  char *payload;

  if (handle->on_message != NULL) {
    payload = malloc(message->payloadlen + 1);
    if (NULL == payload) {
      app_log("MQTT failed to allocate payload buffer.\n");
    } else {
      memcpy(payload, message->payload, message->payloadlen);
      // Make sure that payload is NULL terminated.
      payload[message->payloadlen] = 0;

      handle->on_message(handle, message->topic, payload);

      free(payload);
    }
  }
}

static void mqtt_on_log(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, int level, const char *str)
{
  if (level & LOG_MASK) {
    app_log("MQTT log (%d): %s\n", level, str);
  }
}

#if defined(_WIN32)
static const char * mqtt_err2str(int rc)
{
  char *ret = NULL;
  static char err_str[256];

  if (MOSQ_ERR_ERRNO == rc) {
    // Make sure to have a default output if FormatMessage fails
    // or if error code is not available in errno.
    strncpy(err_str, "Unknown system error", sizeof(err_str));
    if (errno != 0) {
      FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, // dwFlags
                    NULL,                // lpSource
                    errno,               // dwMessageId
                    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // dwLanguageId
                    err_str,             // lpBuffer
                    sizeof(err_str),     // nSize
                    NULL);               // Arguments
    }
    // Make sure that err_str is NULL terminated.
    err_str[sizeof(err_str) - 1] = 0;
    ret = err_str;
  } else {
    ret = (char *)mosquitto_strerror(rc);
  }
  return ret;
}
#else
static const char * mqtt_err2str(int rc)
{
  return (MOSQ_ERR_ERRNO == rc) ? strerror(errno) : mosquitto_strerror(rc);
}
#endif // _WIN32
```

Comment: Please do not just repose the same question that has been closed. If you have updated the old question it will be reviewed for reopening.  Also have you looked at the documentation for the mosquitto client library? https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html